# How to make a space between a line in Java?

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("I have a question, can you assist me?");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("How can I make a gap between these two statements?");
```

I tried to use `println()`, thinking that it would create a blank line, but it didn't.

Comment: `System.out.println("");` or `System.out.print("I have a question, can you assist me?\n");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("I have a question, can you assist me?\n");
        System.out.println("How can I make a gap between these two statements?");
    }
}
```

P.S. `\n` is newline separator and works ok at least on Windows machine. To achieve truly crossplatform separator, use one of methods below:

```
System.out.print("Hello" + System.lineSeparator()); // (for Java 1.7 and 1.8)
System.out.print("Hello" + System.getProperty("line.separator")); // (Java 1.6 and below)
```

Comment: See my comment on @Ronex's answer.  It only works oin Windows if the output is going to "the screen".  If you redirect to a file, a lot of Windows apps won't cope with it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it crossplatform-friendly

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's going on.

```
System.out.print("I have a question, can you assist me?");
```

You have now printed a bunch of characters, all on the same line. As you have used `print` and have not explicitly printed a newline character, the next character printed will also go onto this same line.

```
System.out.println();
```

This prints a *newline character* (`'\n'`), which is *not* the same as printing a blank line. Rather, it will cause the *next* character printed to go onto the line following the current one.

```
System.out.println("How can I make a gap between these two statements?");
```

Since you just printed a newline character, this text will go onto the line directly following your "I have a question" line. Also, since you have called `println`, if you print anything right after this, it will go onto a new line instead of the same one.

To put a blank line between the two statements, you can do this (I know, I know, not entirely cross-platform, but this is just a very simple example):

```
System.out.println("I have a question, can you assist me?");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("How can I make a gap between these two statements?");
```

Since you are now printing *two* newline characters between the two lines, you'll achieve the gap that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that adding a bare "\n" to the string you are outputting is liable to make your code platform specific.  For console output, this is probably OK, but if the file is read by another (platform native) application then you can get strange errors.

Here are some recommend approaches ... that should work on all platforms:

1. Just use println consistently:

   ```
    System.out.println("I have a question, can you assist me?");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("How can I make a gap?");
   ```

   Note: `println` uses the platform default end-of-line sequence.
2. Use String.format:

   ```
    String msg = "I have a question, can you assist me?%n%nHow can " +
                 "I make a gap?%n";
    System.out.print(String.format(msg));
   ```

   Note: `%n` means the platform default end-of-line sequence.

   Note: there is a convenience `printf` method in the `PrintWriter` interface that does the same thing as `String.format`
3. Manually insert the appropriate end-of-line sequence into the string; see the end of @userlond's answer for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use: 
system.out.println("\n");

\n takes you to new line.

Comment: Bad idea.  This won't work properly on Windows ... where the end-of-line sequence is `"\r\n"`.  Hint: try redirecting the output to a file and then opening it with Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.  By that method you can use as much line gap as you want. Just increase or decrease the number of "\n".

```
System.out.print("Hello \n\n\n\n");
System.out.print("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave a single line space in java,you could use

```
System.out.println("");
```

But if you want to leave Multiple line spaces in java,you could use

```
System.out.println("/n/n/n/n");
```

which means that each '/n' represents a single line

Comment: Answer like this was was already posted. Please contribute with something new. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

What about this one?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Something...");
        System.out.printf("%n"); // Not "\n"
        System.out.println("Something else...");
    }
}
```

"%n" should be crossplatform-friendly.